# MySQL table size much larger than size of data in it, causing index scanning queries to be slow

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table which is inserted into and deleted from at a high rate. The number of rows is never larger than a few hundred and I wouldn't expect it to be larger than a few megabytes, but the table size is 20 gigabytes and growing. It's using MySQL 5.6.35, and the engine is InnoDB. I would expect the inserted rows to be inserted in the space left by the deleted rows, but this doesn't appear to be the case. It grows to this level within a week, and at some point it seems some background process starts, and slowly reduces it by a few gigabytes.

The problem with the table being so large is it causes any queries that scan the whole table like `count(*)` run very slowly.

Is there something I can change to prevent the table growing like this?

Comment: In the future, consider [_these techniques_] for big deletes / updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB does free space as you delete, but not instantly. It quickly marks the records as deleted, but the space is marked free later by a purge thread. If you continue to insert more data rapidly, you likely are causing InnoDB to expand the tablespace, at least part of the time, because you're trying to reuse the space from deleted rows before they've been purged.

For example read:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-improved-purge-scheduling.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html

> If you insert and delete rows in smallish batches at about the same rate in the table, the purge thread can start to lag behind and the table can grow bigger and bigger because of all the “dead” rows, making everything disk-bound and very slow. In such a case, throttle new row operations, and allocate more resources to the purge thread by tuning the innodb_max_purge_lag system variable. See Section 14.14, “InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables” for more information.

I have never encountered any site that set `innodb_max_purge_lag`, because it means their continued writes to the database could sometimes be slowed down. They don't usually want that.

Instead, what I've done is set `innodb_purge_threads=4` instead of the default 1. That helps the purge act quickly when it runs.

The purging is further delayed if your app keeps transactions open that need to hold onto those deleted rows to satisfy their REPEATABLE-READ view of the database. It doesn't matter how fast the purge is or how many threads you have to do the purge, if purging is prevented by open transactions' snapshot requirements.

You should commit transactions promptly, and not leave them open for indefinite amounts of time. Or change your transaction isolation level to READ-COMMITTED so your transactions don't need the database to retain old record versions.

Comment: Is extra purge threads likely to help when it's just the one table? The documentation seemed to suggest otherwise.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would expect that it depends on which rows you deleted, and how likely it is for there to be overlap as the purge threads work.

Comment: @BillKarwin I am also facing same issue with a large innodb table. My delete rate is far more than insert rate and the rows I am deleting are very old and not read/updated in any queries. Still the data size and index size both are growing.

Comment: @CJ. You might have table fragmentation, where pages and extents are partially filled, but mostly empty. Running an OPTIMIZE TABLE (or any ALTER TABLE that copies the table) should defragment it, copying the tables to a new tablespace in defragmented format. If you don't want the table to be locked, use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try OPTIMIZE TABLE on this table.

> OPTIMIZE TABLE reorganizes the physical storage of table data and
>   associated index data, to reduce storage space and improve I/O
>   efficiency when accessing the table. The exact changes made to each
>   table depend on the storage engine used by that table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html